# PeerJS video stream not working when using iPhone - iOS to Android or iOS to iOS - Node.js

Tags: ios, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

I have been testing this program on my Mac Laptop and it has been working fine. It would show the video from MacOS to Samsung OneUI Android, and that worked. The problem is that when I use iOS (I tried from the iPhone SE 2) and connected it to my Samsung phone (Android), it would connect, but the video did not show. The space was filled for the video (meaning the connection was there), but there was no contents of the video. It WILL show its own video contents (just the iPhone SE camera contents to itself), just not the peers video, but I know I am receiving the connection (due to socket.io and PeerJS getting to the point of trying to create the video). PS: I even tried logging 'User Connected' to the console to see if they were connecting, and they were.

I have tried putting the following:

```
video.playsInline = true;
```

Or this:

```
video. setAttribute('autoplay', '');
video. setAttribute('muted', '');
video. setAttribute('playsinline', '');
```

But it still did not work.

Do any of you know how to fix this issue?

Full Code (Client):

```
const socket = io('/');

const videos = document.getElementById('videos');
const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
let alreadyDoneUsers = {};
let myUserId = null;

const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: '/',
    port: '8090'
});

myVideo.playsInline = true;
myVideo.muted = true;
var getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.mozGetUserMedia;

getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
})
.then((stream) => {
    addVideo(myVideo, stream); 
    
    myPeer.on('call', (call) => {
        call.answer(stream);
        const video = document.createElement('video');
        video.playsInline = true;
        call.on('stream', (peerStream) => {
            addVideo(video, peerStream); 
        });
        socket.on('user-disconnected', (userIdDisconnected) => {
            if (call.peer == userIdDisconnected || call.peer == myUserId) {
                video.remove();
            }
        })
    })
    socket.on('user-connected', (userId) => {
        console.log('User Connected');
        const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
        const video = document.createElement('video');
        video.playsInline = true;
        call.on('stream', (peerStream) => {
            addVideo(video, peerStream); 
        });
        socket.emit('user-id-send', myUserId);
        socket.on('user-disconnected', (userIdDisconnected) => {
            if (userId == userIdDisconnected) {
                video.remove();
                call.close();
            }
        })
    });
});

myPeer.on('open', (id) => {
    myUserId = id;
    socket.emit('joined', ROOM_ID, id); 
});

function addVideo(video, stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        video.play(); 
    });
    videos.append(video);
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, chrome laptop to android or chrome laptop to another chrome laptop OK But chrome laptop to iphone fails for data or streams. I initially test with data (strings) as it's less complicated than streaming video.

Comment: I have just read that iOS has stopped supporting WebRTC. This could very well be the issue as this is what I was using. Here is where I found this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_mobile_support.htm. I found this under the iOS section.

Comment: @Adule That article is completely wrong, I couldn't see when it was written so maybe it's out of date. I managed to get it working with peerjs and IOS by using the latest version 1.3.2, the previous version will not work with video and IOS, that threw me for a while as I didn't realise I didn't have the latest version!

Comment: @user2677034 How did you manage to make it work in the end? Any sample code would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @alex.b make sure to use the latest version, then it will work with IOS.

Comment: did you solve it your problem can you share it please

Comment: No, I still have not solved this problem. It was an older project so I just gave up.